# no se puede generar el proyecto que no tiene establecido un archivo de compatibilidad binaria vb6

Tags: vb6

Este error me aparece al momento de intentar crear el exe de mi proyecto de vb6,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

primero creo el dll, eso se hace correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando intento crear el exe es cuando me aparece el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hace añares que no veo vb6, pero por ahí esto te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338401/vb-6-the-project-not-be-built-because-it-references-a-project-which-does-not-ha

Comment: ya lo resolvi, en el proyecto donde esta la capa de datos tenia que poner como configuracion binaria y elegir el archivo dll que fue generado apartir de dicho proyecto, eso fue todo lo que hice